# Webbrowser control and certenroll

Tags: vb.net, webbrowser-control, certenroll

Hi I have a really simple program, just a webbrowser control and one line of code.

```
Webbrowser1.navigate "www.sspcrs.ie/sha2"
```

This gives a vb scripting error/exception about being unable to create a certenroll object.

If I go to the same url in internet explorer there is no problem.

For what's it worth I have tried varying the security settings in internet explorer but it does not seem to make any difference.

In the fail situation the vb script on the page tries about 3 different ways to create a cert object and then if there is an error in all three puts up an error message suggesting that activex objects be allowed and turning of protected mode.

In the success situation a Web Access dialog appears asking the user if they are willing to "allow this site to perform a digital certificate operation".

Comment: This link is C#, but there should be no problem to convert it to VB.Net: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/alejacma/2008/09/05/how-to-create-a-certificate-request-with-certenroll-and-net-c/

Comment: Could you append details of the error/exception and situation when "there is no problem"?

Comment: @muffi  thanks for the prompt reply i will certainly look at that link.

Comment: @rudolf_franek Thanks I have added something just now.